# Unhandled exception at 0x5E10F1C0 (ucrtbased.dll) in HW 5 Rational pt2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC. occurred

Tags: c++, pointers, strcpy

I'm confused why I am getting this error. I've looked around and have found someone with a similar error, and their issue was not allocating enough new memory for NULL. I didn't think that was the problem with mine, because I added strlen + 1? I'm lost...

```
//Copy Constructor
Rational::Rational(const Rational& other) :
    m_numerator(other.m_numerator), m_denominator(other.m_denominator), 
m_name(NULL)
{
    m_name = NULL;
    if (other.m_name != NULL)
    {
        this->m_name = new char[strlen(other.m_name) + 1]; //ErrorMarkHere
        strcpy(this->m_name, other.m_name);
    }
}
```

Comment: 0xCC means you've read [uninitialized memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714)

Comment: Error is on read, not write... `other.m_name` is non-NULL, but is it actually a properly terminated string?

Answer (score 1):

`0xCCCCCCCC` means uninitialized memory with some compilers. Pretty much the only thing that could fail on that line would be `strlen(other.m_name)`, where `other.m_name` probably is the pointer mentioned before. How is `other` constructed from where this crashed?

Comment: Rational& Rational::operator + (const Rational& x)
{
 this->add(x);
 return *this;

}

Comment: This is the add function:                                                                                             Rational Rational::add(const Rational& input)
{
 Rational r;
 r.m_denominator = m_denominator * input.m_denominator;
 r.m_numerator = (m_numerator * input.m_denominator) + (input.m_numerator * m_denominator);
 r.reduce();
 return r;
}

Comment: Right, but how is `m_name` initialized?